# Center div over multiple divs

Tags: html, css

So I'm having a hard time aligning a div over another div with a bunch of images as a (pseudo-) "background" like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2Vmk.png

But I've tried positioning it as absolute and relative and it always ends up like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEchc.png

My code:

```
<body class="site com_content view-featured no-layout no-task itemid-101">

<!-- Body -->
<div class="body">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <main id="content" role="main" class="span12">
                <!-- Begin Content -->

                <div id="modInistagram">
                   <div class="cbinstaphotobox">
                       <div class="col-lg-12">
                           <figure class="figurefx dualpanels">
                               <img>
                           </figure>
                           <figure class="figurefx dualpanels">
                               <img>
                           </figure>
                           <figure class="figurefx dualpanels">
                               <img>
                           </figure>
                           <figure class="figurefx dualpanels">
                               <img>
                           </figure>
                           <figure class="figurefx dualpanels">
                               <img>
                           </figure>
                           <figure class="figurefx dualpanels">
                               <img>
                           </figure>
                           <figure class="figurefx dualpanels">
                               <img>
                           </figure>
                           <figure class="figurefx dualpanels">
                               <img>
                           </figure>
                           <figure class="figurefx dualpanels">
                               <img>
                           </figure>
                           <figure class="figurefx dualpanels">
                               <img>
                           </figure>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           <div class="custom">
               <div class="logo">
                   <img src="tcsslogosmall.png" alt="logo">
                   <div class="socialicons">
                       <a href="facebook.com/YYYshop">
                           <img src="fb.png">
                       </a>
                       <a href="instagram.com">
                           <img src="instgr.png">
                       </a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="contacts">
                       <h4 style="text-align: center;"></h4>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <!-- End Content -->
       </div>
       </div>
       </main>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

The "custom" div is the one that I want to "float" over the "modInstagram".

Comment: `position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;`

Comment: My bad...
https://jsfiddle.net/24157Lmf/

Comment: @Sauce I've updated your jsFiddle with what I think you're after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap the images and overlay in a parent element with `position: relative`  you will be able to use `position: absolute` on the overlay element to position it on top of the images.

Here's a quick example:
https://jsfiddle.net/hmpxdezy/1/

**Edited answer:**

Based off your jsFiddle, is it `div.custom` you want to position over the top of `div#modInistagram`?

If so, here is an updated fiddle to give you an idea of how to achieve what you want with your existing markup:
https://jsfiddle.net/24157Lmf/1/

You need to add `position: relative` to `main#content` and add `position: absolute` to `div.custom`. From there you can center align the overlay element using a similar method to my [original jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmpxdezy/1/) with `left: 50%` and a negative `margin-left` with a value that is half the width of the element you want to center.